# Porque no funciona emit en Socket.io? Angular/ExpessJS

Tags: angular, express, socket.io

Estoy haciendo una comunicación sencilla con socket.io, es decir, cuando hago una consulta al endpoint `changeStatus` función la cual se encuentra en `userController` en una carpeta de controllers la cual es llamada en otra de rutas(routes/user.js) que es una lista de endpoints y a su vez es llamada en app.js para mantener todo separado, el cual hace un cambio en la base de datos, es el siguiente:

userController.js :

```
async function changeStatus(req, res) { //cambia status
try {
        //cosas de la base de datos

        io.emit('changeStatus',()=>{
            console.log("enviado...")
        })

        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Status updated :)"
        })
    }
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
 }
```

Ahora, el servidor está configurado de la siguiente forma, hay un archivo el cual contiene la configuración del socket llamado socketConfig.js:

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

     function configureSocket(server) {
     const io = socketIO(server);
     return io;
}
module.exports = configureSocket;
```

Al mismo tiempo en app.js está de esta forma:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
    console.log("conected: ");

    app.use('/user', userRoutes)

    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        console.log("disconected")
    })
})

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server On");
})
```

Así queda bien configurado el servidor, la línea de app.use dentro del io.on es porque pensé que así si iba a funcionar. Ahora como podemos notar cada que se haga una petiocion a `changeStatus` hace un emit , ahora lo recibo en Angular de la siguiente forma, este es mi servicio el cual es llamado en el componente:

```
export class SocketService {

   private socket: any

   constructor() {

       this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{ transports : ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] });

       this.socket.on('connect', () => {
           console.log('Conectado al servidor Socket.IO: ');
       });

       this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
           console.log('Desconectado del servidor Socket.IO');
       });

       this.socket.on('changeStatus',()=>{
           console.log("reibido..")
       });
       }
```

Y aquí viene el problema, según tengo entendido la función on de socket.io escucha al emit si su tag corresponde y eso queda claro con mis funciones on de `disconnect` y `connect` pues ambos funcionan y en la consola de ambas me imprime que en efecto estan conectados, y se desconectan bien, perooo cuando hago alguna solicitud a la funcion de `changeStatus` donde se encuentra el emit, en express si entra e imprime "enviando.." sin embargo en Angular no pasa nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora según tengo entendido, si cualquier solicitud entra al end point emit lanza esa escucha a todos los usuarios conectados, por lo que si hago la solicitud de changeStatus por PostMan o similares esta debería de enviar a los usuarios conectados al servidor el mensaje de emit.

Y así lo hago, por post man hago la consulta esperando que en mi aplicación angular reciba el emit y saber que se hizo un cambio en la base de datos, para posteriormente hacer algo mas elaborado que solo eso.

Si puedes ayudarme muchas gracias, espero haber sido claro